# Native query in spring not working with inner select in where clause

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I have a native query with inner select statement which requires a where
condition on one of the attributes from the outer table. The query work fine when I run it in mySQL but it throw SQLGrammerException when I run it through spring.

01:38:24.429 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
01:38:24.444 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/genchi] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1024)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1053)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.count(JpaQueryExecution.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.lambda$doExecute$0(JpaQueryExecution.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(PageableExecutionUtils.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:194

```
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM script_result SR LEFT JOIN script S ON 
   SR.script_id = S.ID "   
  + "INNER JOIN server_job_run SJR ON SR.server_job_run_id = SJR.id "  
  + "INNER JOIN suite_server_job SSJ ON SSJ.id = SJR.suite_server_job_id "
  + "LEFT JOIN suite ST ON ST.id = SSJ.suite_id "
  + "where (COALESCE(:project_id) is null or project_id IN (:project_id)) "
  + "AND (:suite_id is null or suite_id = :suite_id) "
  + "AND (:environment_name is null or E.name = :environment_name) "
  + "AND SJR.id = (SELECT inner_sjr.id FROM server_job_run inner_sjr "
  + "WHERE inner_sjr.suite_server_job_id = SSJ.id "
  + "ORDER BY inner_sjr.id DESC "
  + "LIMIT 1)"
  , nativeQuery = true)        


(SELECT inner_sjr.id FROM server_job_run inner_sjr "
  + "WHERE inner_sjr.suite_server_job_id = SSJ.id "
  + "ORDER BY inner_sjr.id DESC "
  + "LIMIT 1)"
```

In this inner select when I give some hardcoded value to SSJ.id then it works but doesn't work otherwise

Comment: `LEFT JOIN INNER JOIN` doesn't look like valid SQL to me.

Comment: typo corrected.. main issue is to get the inner join to work

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.